# Proving the distributive law of a Dedekind Cut

Tags: analysis

In the Book (Principles of mathematics, by Walter Rudin)
they just state the proof of the positive cuts

how do I prove the one with the negative cuts?

Comment: You can see Ethan Bloch, [The real numbers and real analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=r0qcU9U2_I4C&pg=PA46) (2011), page 46, for the discussion of some of the four cases.

Comment: You have to consider cases (Rudin defines multiplication by cases).